# Resultado de um SELECT em PostgreSQL não está sendo o mesmo no SQLite

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

Boa noite pessoal, desenvolvi uma Query no PostgreSQL para aplicar um SELECT nos meus dados impondo algumas regras, e essas regras são muito importantes para mim obter o resultado correto no final da seleção.

O filtro que precisava desenvolver era esse:

> **GSM** que for repetido, e tiver em ambos o **STATUS** = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA' e seu **MOTIVO_ENVIO** for igual, importe apenas um registro, cuja **DATA_ALTERACAO** for mais recente.

A resolução dele para rodar no PostgreSQL foi essa:

```sql
SELECT ex.gsm, ex.motivo_envio, ex.status, ex.data_ativacao, ex.data_importacao, ex.data_alteracao
FROM (SELECT gsm, MAX(data_alteracao) AS last_date FROM anomalias GROUP BY gsm) lst
INNER JOIN anomalias ex ON (lst.gsm = ex.gsm) AND (ex.data_alteracao = lst.last_date)
WHERE ex.status = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'
AND EXISTS (SELECT tmp.gsm FROM anomalias tmp
WHERE tmp.gsm = ex.gsm
AND tmp.motivo_envio = ex.motivo_envio
AND tmp.status = ex.status
GROUP BY tmp.gsm, tmp.motivo_envio, tmp.status
HAVING COUNT(tmp.gsm) > 1)
```

Esse filtro me retorna **9 registros**, e é exatamente a quantidade de registros correta que precisava.
Meu problema está sendo quando coloco esse filtro para rodar no `SQLite` ele me retorna **3 registros** a mais, e isso não pode acontecer, preciso muito que ele obedeça está Query, eu copiei exatamente do mesmo jeito que está no PostgreSQL e pus no SQLite, mas está me retornando dados indesejáveis.

---

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor, não sei se está query que fiz é o melhor método pra seguir a regra que preciso, a regra como mencionei acima é essa:

> **GSM** que for repetido, e tiver em ambos o **STATUS** = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA' e seu **MOTIVO_ENVIO** for igual, importe apenas um registro, cuja **DATA_ALTERACAO** for mais recente.

Caso alguém precise do conteúdo do Banco de Dados pra testar aqui está: https://ghostbin.com/paste/9uqnn

Comment: As bases são iguais ?

Comment: Sim @Motta as iguais, se quiser posso disponibilizar o arquivo de Banco de Dados em SQLite também, eu também disponibilizei o `INSERT` do conteúdo completo do Banco de Dados, pus no ghostbin: https://ghostbin.com/paste/9uqnn se tu puder me ajudar mano, serio preciso muito, eu tinha terminado o projeto ai quando fui verificar o resultado tenho essa surpresa.

Comment: @Magno A estrutura da tabela `anomalias` também está igual em ambos os bancos ? Você poderia alterar a sua pergunta incluindo a estrutura da tabela na edição ?

Comment: Está exatamente igual em ambos os Bancos tanto PostgreSQL quanto SQLite, afinal são os mesmo dados, mesmas colunas etc.

Comment: @Magno: Sem saber quais são os tipos de cada uma das colunas da tabela `anomalias` fica dificil compreender e reproduzir o seu problema.

Comment: @Lacobus no PostgreSQL tenho os tipos de dados da seguinte forma: `gsm = text | motivo_envio = text | status = text | data_alteracao = date | data_importacao = date | data_alteracao = date` e no SQLite também.

Comment: Os campos que você relacionou na cláusula GROUP BY não constam da lista de campos do SELECT. Tem certeza de que foi este o comando que você rodou no PostgreSQL?

Comment: Sim @anonimo funciona perfeitamente no PostgreSQL na verdade se eu acrescentar esses campos que estão "teoricamente faltando" na query ele me da erro, testei fazer isso no SQLite e não deu erro, mas deu na mesma, continua me trazendo esses 3 dados a mais, você poderia me ajudar? tipo não tenho muito conhecimento com SQL, você consegue reescrever está query pra mim?

Answer (score 1):

A diferença pode estar na forma como cada um dos bancos de dado está interpretando as strings contendo datas no formato `DD/MM/YYYY`.

O `SQLite3` interpreta strings contendo datas no formato [`ISO8601`](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype), ou seja: `YYYY-MM-DD`, enquanto o `PostgreSQL` usa uma variável de ambiente chamada [`DateStyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) para fazer esse controle.

Se você pretende usar strings contendo datas no formato `DD/MM/YYYY` no `SQLite3`, você deve usar a função `strftime()`, veja só:

```
INSERT INTO
    export
VALUES
    (
      '31992387535',
      'TROCA DE APARELHOS_REEMBOLSO - REBATE',
      'LIBERADO',
      strftime('%d/%m/%Y','27/02/2019'),
      strftime('%d/%m/%Y','27/02/2019'),
      strftime('%d/%m/%Y','01/03/2019')
    );
```

Ou então, ajustar suas strings para o formato esperado pelo `SQLite3`:

```
INSERT INTO
    export
VALUES
    (
      '31992387535',
      'TROCA DE APARELHOS_REEMBOLSO - REBATE',
      'LIBERADO',
      '2019-02-27',
      '2019-02-27',
      '2019-03-01'
    );
```

Reparei também que você usa caracteres especiais em suas strings, por exemplo:

```
...
ex.status = 'ANOMALIA TEMPORÁRIA'
...
```

As strings contendo esses caracteres especiais foram gravadas corretamente no banco de dados onde você está executando seu `SELECT` ?!

Comment: Eu não consigo usar esse strftime('%d/%m/%Y','27/02/2019') passando ele direito no SELECT para fazer essa conversão não? pois eu teria um problema grande em fazer dessa forma pois esses dados vem de uma planilha Excel, e uso o Python pra criar o Banco de Dados SQLite e ele já importa todo o conteúdo da Planilha pra dentro da tabela, eu não preciso usar o INSERT INTO pra por o conteúdo na planilha uso um loop para isso com um função de uma Biblioteca chamada Pandas (Python), as colunas de datas estão no formato `DD/MM/YYYY` mas será que realmente isso seria o empecilho para esse resultado?

Comment: Já verificou se `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM anomalias;` retorna a mesma quantidade de registros nos dois bancos de dados ?

Comment: sim a mesma quantidade em ambos

Comment: subi todo banco de dados pra um [site](https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-5c85b873ebf77js8jt3nx39k) que roda SQlite, se tu puder me ajudar mano, sinceramente preciso muito mesmo, tinha um prazo pra entrega amanhã sinceramente não sei o que fazer :/

Comment: @Locupos Sim caracteres especiais funcionam perfeitamente, pois ao termino da consulta com o SELECT eu pego todo esse resultado e exporto para o Excel novamente usando a Biblioteca Pandas, em relação a Data, e Caracteres Especiais funcionam perfeitamente, o problema é no resultado errado que a Query que mostrei no Post está trazendo, ele traz 3 resultados a mais, sendo que a mesma funciona perfeitamente no PostgreSQL

Comment: Os dados podem estar sendo corrompidos durante o processo de importação/exportação. O erro pode estar relacionado ao encoding das strings ou ao formato da data.

Comment: Acho que não, até porque se fosse isso os outros 2 filtros que tenho aqui daria problema, ao todo tenho 3 filtros, ambos foram criados no PostgreSQL, e eu passei eles para o SQLite, os 2 primeiros funcionaram perfeitamente, mas esse terceiro me trouxe 3 dados a mais, a exportação e importação ocorre sem erros, ao final da exportação confiro cada registro pra ver se não ficou estranho nem nada, e está tudo correto, você consegue reescrever essa query pra uma forma mais objetiva? não tenho muito conhecimento com Banco de Dados, penei muito pra fazer essa Query, se puder ajudar agradeço!